# How to use SpellingResult class in SolrJ

Tags: java, solr, solrj, spell-checking

I'm using SolrJ. But through the API documentation could not figure out how to use the particular class to receive the response of the spell checker.
i have a search component defined in solrconfig.xml for performing the checking

Comment: "Explain with examples"...  I better comply before I get assimilated by the borg

Comment: just some way to know how to use it

Comment: I understood what you meant! it's just a little rude/brutal... no wonder you didn't get many answers yet

Comment: yes ... i'm really sorry for this .. David... I'll Keep note of it .. thanx !!!!

Comment: @DavidM you first comment was funny, your third was not needed (ie "no wonder...") and is far worse than unintentionally English language/culture faux pas by the OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you already found the solution, anyway the `SpellingResult` class comes with Solr, while you're using SolrJ to access a Solr server, if I'm not wrong. So, you should use the specific classes that come with SolrJ; the `QueryResponse` object contains a `SpellCheckResponse` object with all the information you're looking for.

```
SolrServer solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr");
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("qt", "/spell");
params.set("q", "whatever");
params.set("spellcheck", "on");
//params.set("spellcheck.build", "true");

QueryResponse response = solr.query(params);
SpellCheckResponse spellCheckResponse = response.getSpellCheckResponse();
if (!spellCheckResponse.isCorrectlySpelled()) {
    for (Suggestion suggestion : response.getSpellCheckResponse().getSuggestions()) {
        logger.debug("original token: " + suggestion.getToken() + " - alternatives: " + suggestion.getAlternatives());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.